# Orbeon separate deployment

Tags: orbeon

I followed http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-with-java-applications and successfully got separate deployments working.

I would like to create my own resources folder which will have some configuration files like properties-local.xml and custom XBL controls. I got this working by copying my resources under orbeon.war/WEB-INF/resources. I would like them to go under myapp.war/WEB-INF/resources. How can I achieve that?

How can I configure a resource manager to pickup my resources which are under myapp.war/WEB-INF/resources without modifying orbeon?

I have seen this http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/overriding-adding-resources but not sure how this applies in the context of separate deployments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orbeon has a series of [resource managers](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/resource-managers), able to load resources from:

- classloader -> resources can be packaged in JAR files
- webapp -> resources can be put e.g. under WEB-INF/resources
- filesystem -> resources can be put anywhere on disk

What you want to do here it seems is having one WAR file access resources stored in another WAR file. I don't think that this is possible with the current resource managers, unless you setup the filesystem, in which case you need to specify an absolute path to the location of the resources on disk.

In theory, I think it should be possible to enhance the [webapp resource manager](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/java/org/orbeon/oxf/resources/WebAppResourceManagerImpl.java) to access other servlet contexts. So you could tell the Orbeon webapp to load resources from your own webapp.

BTW this would still mean that you would need to update the Orbeon WAR's web.xml to configure the resource manager.